# how can i combine extjs and infovis spacetree

Tags: extjs4.1, infovis

i am new to extjs and infovis.
i am trying to implement a page which will have 2 components. the upper is a extjs grid wich is rendered with  by some data recived from server--> extjs store.
i need the lower component to be a spacetree which will be rendered by same data.
in addition i need to listen to events on the grid and marke the selected nodes in the space tree.
does any one has some example of integration extjs with infoVis?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've successfully integrated a spacetree into an app using extjs.  My example below plots the tree in a window, (and is significantly edited for clarity) but hopefully it will give you an idea.  The main idea here is that we're dynamically creating a div with a random id, and attaching that div to a panel and rendering it.  After that, we can pass the div's id into the injectInto parameter of the spacetree initialization and the ST will be drawn on the extjs component.

Note that the ST is actually initialized in a doRefresh function that is tied to the window and called externally.  In my example, I'm retrieving data directly from the server with a jquery post, for your implementation you could do something similar with your grid.  Simply listen to events on the store, and call a refresh function on the spacetree's parent component.

```
function createSpacetreeWindow() {
var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: ' Window Title',
    id: windowId,
    height: 600,
    maxheight: 600,
    width: 1000,
    layout: {
        type: 'anchor',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    doRefresh: function () {
        var existing = Ext.getCmp('panel_' + divid);
        if (existing) {
            existing.destroy();
        }
        var newdivid = randomString();
        var divA = document.createElement("div");
        divA.setAttribute("id", newdivid);
        divA.setAttribute("class", "repoPathView");
        win.add({
            id: 'panel_' + divid,
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 600,
            width: 1000,
            layout: 'fit',
            contentEl: divA
        });
        loadSpaceTree(newdivid, repPathId);
    }
});

win.show();
win.doRefresh();
}

function loadSpacetree(divid, rpId) {

// retrieve the data via jquery POST. 
var url = GetSpacetreeUrl();
$.post(url, { myId: rpId }, function (data) {     

    //Create a new ST instance
    var st = new $jit.ST({
        injectInto: divid,
        duration: 100,
        transition: $jit.Trans.Quart.easeInOut,
        levelDistance: 50,

        offsetX: 350,
        constrained: false,
        siblingOffset: 100,
        levelsToShow: 100,

        Navigation: {
            enable: true,
            panning: true
        },

        Node: {
            type: 'networkelement',
            overridable: true
        },

        Edge: {
            type: 'bezier',
            overridable: true,
            lineWidth: 2,
            color: '#4CC417'
        }
    });

    //load json data
    st.loadJSON(data);
    st.compute();

    //emulate a click on the root node.
    st.onClick(st.root);
});
```

}